# What is this decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-decomposition

What is the name of the decomposition shown below?
[image: inea]

Comment: This looks like a simple matrix multiplication, no fancy name required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically a QR factorisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix).

It is quite trivial, but you can indeed observe that on the Right Hand Side, the matrix on the left is orthogonal, and the matrix on the right is upper-triangular.

**Edit**

As a commenter pointed out, the left matrix is not necessarily orthogonal. However, it at least has orthogonal columns (unless $f = 0$).

Comment: The matrix on the left is only orthogonal if $|f| = 1$.